# change color button with click on other button in javafx

Tags: javafx

I have 64 buttons.
I want when click on one of Button change color other button and other Button each time diffrent from Previous.
I want make ottlo game and this part of code for offer Authorized houses.
thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an onClick method, and set this all of your buttons.

In the onClick method, you can get all of your buttons by `scene.lookup()` method - you need to set styleclass for this buttons. For example: the css class is `my-colored-buttons`, then you can call `scene.lookup(".my-colored-buttons")`;

Another solution is add all of yout buttons to your controller. This is not too good solution I think, hard to maintain.

```
@FXML
private Button btn1;

@FXML
private Button btn2;

@FXML
private Button btn3;

...
```

After you get all of the buttons, get current button from event variable, and change only the other buttons color. So the currently clicked button will not change.